# Shower tile inside corner vertical joint

Tags: tile

Is it true it should be caulked ( not grouted) at vertical inside corner?  what is the best way to keep epoxy away from the vertical joints when grouting epoxy?

Comment: My personal approach is to grout as normal and caulk when it proves necessary. There's no reason that a corner moves more than a joint in the field if the framing is done well.

Answer (score 1):

Inside corners should always be caulked, not grouted. Walls move, and when grout moves it cracks. If you're using epoxy grout on the walls you can actually use it in the corners too but keep in mind it's more difficult to work with especially in corners. If you're using epoxy grout on the walls and going to caulk the corners, epoxy grout the horizontal lines first and then caulk the corner after the grout sets.

Comment: Can we just put a narrow strip of masking tape or duct tape at inside vertical joints to keep it clear from the grout when we grout with epoxy?

Comment: You would be better off using a small putty knife to do the horizontal lines.  A piece of tape might leave too big a space.

Comment: I use epoxy grout in corner’s all the time, yes it is harder to work than calk but it looks much better than calking.